Is this a 'standard' elliptic integral?
I have come across the following integral that I need to evaluate:
$$f_1(\mu) = \int_0^\pi \frac{\text{d} \alpha}{(1 - \mu \cos \alpha)^{3/2}} $$
It is given in a 2005 paper by F.R. Zypman (https://pubs.aip.org/aapt/ajp/article/74/4/295/1056228), in relation to calculating the off-axis electric field due to a uniformly-charged ring. It seems to be a type of elliptic integral and I am wondering if it is related to any of the 'standard' elliptic integrals, for example, the complete elliptic integral of the first kind:
$$f_2(\mu) = \int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{\text{d} \theta}{\sqrt{(1 - k^2 \sin^2 \theta)}} $$
They don't seem to be equivalent, since as $\mu,k \to 0$ , the integrals are out by a factor of 2. However, I am wondering if there is a simple relation between them? If so, then it would presumably be straightforward to evaluate $f_1(\mu)$ using standard elliptic integral package functions, rather than having to evaluate it numerically.
The linked paper by Zypman solves $f_2$ numerically, along with another elliptic integral:
$$f_3(\mu) = \int_0^\pi \frac{\cos \alpha \ \text{d} \alpha}{(1 - \mu \cos \alpha)^{3/2}} $$
but doesn't seem to give any hints as to whether/how they can be evaluated analytically, and if they relate to any of the 'standard' elliptic integrals.

Maple says
$$
\int_{0}^{\pi}\! \left( 1-\mu\,\cos \left( \alpha \right)  \right) ^{-
{\frac{3}{2}}}\,{\rm d}\alpha=-2\,{\frac {1}{\sqrt {\mu+1} \left( -1+
\mu \right) }{E} \left( {\frac {\sqrt {2}\sqrt {\mu}}{
\sqrt {\mu+1}}} \right) }
$$
where $E$ is a complete elliptic integral.
Note $E(\sqrt{s})$ in Maple's sense is $E[s]$ is Mathematica's sense.

This is really helpful, thanks! So they're not equivalent, but there seems to be a fairly straightforward relationship between them. I will try using Maple for the $f_3(\mu)$ integral as well.

One  aspect of this formula which may seem problematic on first inspection is the range of $\mu$: the integral is well-defined for $-1<\mu<1$, but results in imaginary arguments of $E$ (in Maple's sense). But the integral is in fact a symmetric function of $\mu$ in this range, so one never needs to actually compute these cases separately.

Continuing in this vein, I think one should have $$\int_{0}^{\pi}! \left( 1-\mu,\cos \left( \alpha \right)  \right)^{-{\frac{1}{2}}},{\rm d}\alpha=\frac{2}{\sqrt{\mu+1}}K\left(\sqrt{\frac{2\mu}{\mu+1}}\right)$$ where $K$ is the complete elliptic integral of the first kind. (This is in Maple's sense, though I derived it using Mathematica.) This combined with Yves's second observation yields a result in terms of $E,K$ for $f_3(\mu)$.
